# JWT: issuer_not_found and/or unsupported grant type

Tags: php, jwt, docusignapi

PHP 7.4, Windows Server 2012, IIS 8.

I've been all over stackOverflow and docusign's own documentation, but I can't get past the JWT token request. I've tried:

- the instructions using jwt.io
- the instructions for building the JWT
  request manually
- using the SDK method requestJWTApplicationToken
- every variation of the aud tag I can think of
- I've verified
  account-d.docusign.com, the app id, and the user id
- The app has been granted consent
- I even started from scratch, created a second application, granted consent, etc...

When I use the SDK, I get "issuer_not_found". The other methods, "unsupported_grant_type."

I've been poking at this thing all week and I haven't yet found a combination of circumstances that doesn't throw an error. The boss is rattling my cage every day.

Can someone get me past this hurdle?

**issuer_not_found:**

```
// bring in the docusign SDK
require_once("./docusign/vendor/autoload.php");
// bring in the config file provided by the QuickStart on Docusign
require_once("$admin/esign/ds_config.php");

// use the docusign client namespace
use DocuSign\eSign\Client\ApiClient;

// create the SDK client object
$client = new ApiClient();

// get the private key, saved in a file after being copy/pasted from the application 
$rsa_private_key = file_get_contents("$admin/esign/private.key");
// get the client_id a.k.a. app id from the config file provided by the QuickStart on Docusign
$client_id = $GLOBALS['JWT_CONFIG']['ds_client_id'];

// $user_id = $GLOBALS['JWT_CONFIG']['ds_impersonated_user_id'];

// call the SDK api for the application JWT token, lifted from the SDK sample code
$test = $client->requestJWTApplicationToken($client_id, $rsa_private_key);
// $test = $client->requestJWTUserToken($client_id, $user_id, $rsa_private_key);

// display the inevitable error message
echo('<pre>[97616] $test:'  . print_r($test, 1)) . '</pre>';
```

**unsupported_grant_type**

```
use Firebase\JWT\JWT;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$header = ["alg"=>"RS256","typ"=>"JWT"];
        
$privateKey = file_get_contents($this->path_admin . "/esign/private.key");

// $publicKey = file_get_contents($this->path_admin . "/esign/public.key");

$expiration = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()) . " +1 hours"); // subtract 12 hours

$payload = json_encode(array(
    "iss" => $GLOBALS['JWT_CONFIG']['ds_client_id'],
    "aud" => "account-d.docusign.net",
    "iat" => time(),
    "sub" => $GLOBALS['JWT_CONFIG']['ds_impersonated_user_id'],
    "exp" => $expiration,
    "scope" => "signature"
));

$jwt = JWT::encode($payload, $privateKey, 'RS256');

$client = new Client();

$response = $client->request('POST', 'https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token', [
    'body' => json_encode([
        'grant_type' => 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
        'assertion'  => $jwt
    ])
]);
```

Comment: Can you explain in your own words - only for the first case - what the code does? Step by step?

Comment: @hakre Added comments inline in the code.

Comment: inline comments are not that well for what I was aiming for, but at least ;). so I guess these kind of intentions were clear already with the code, I was more looking for your own understanding. for example when you display the error message, is it expected to you that you get the error or not? if unexpected, how do you explain what the code does (displaying that error message) in your own words?

Comment: And the inline comments for the commented-out code are missing. If it's easier for you to delete that code already, delete it - don't comment it out and additionally comment it (as you didn't comment it when you said you commented all inline, it looks like that code is dead and should go away)

Comment: I added the comments after your request, so you may need to refresh the page.

Just so we're clear - it kind of sounds like it's not - this is for the DocuSign API.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, or the point of explaining the code in my own words, for that matter, unless you're trolling me. Of course the intention is to get no error messages: I expect to get a JWT token that I can then use to call the eSign API. The two blocks of code are two different attempts. The first code uses the docusign SDK, the second code is the SDK code written out longhand. There is no dead code, it's two different files, and they should return the same thing: a JWT token.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234705/discussion-between-hakre-and-bill-in-kansas-city).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a "simple" configuration problem, check you're using the correct values (perhaps easier said than done).

And first of all troubleshooting 101: If the simplest and first try already give you an error, concentrate on this one and only this one until it works. Just in case this was not obvious.

For **issuer_not_found**:

> Issuer_not_found: The integration key in the iss (issuer) parameter is unavailable in the current environment. This can also mean a mismatch in the aud (audience) value and the environment being hit: for example, using an aud value of account.docusign.com while requesting a token from https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token.

For **unsupported_grant_type**: You can solve it when you solved the first error - Joke aside:

Adhere as much as possible to the official docs, e.g. [When using JWT authentication, how do I troubleshoot an invalid_grant or other errors?](https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/DocuSign-Developer-FAQs-General-Administration-and-Authentication#Troubleshoot-JWT-invalid_grant) until it clicks.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, the issuer_not_found error came down to a mis-match between the "aud" parameter of the request body and the URL: the SDK does not look to the config files for the POST url, it merely defaults to the live URL, account.docusign.com. To use account-d, you must explicitly set that value (a fact that I can't find in the SDK's documentation.) Many thanks to @hakre for the nudge in the right direction.